# How to insert a simple rectangle color swatch?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a GUI that currently looks like the following:
[image]

Towards the left side of the GUI, I want to insert two rectangle colour swatches, representing the current "foreground colour" and "background colour" in Adobe Photoshop.

Please ignore the colour names in the drop down control.

I have looked at the available controls for `GUI` command, none of the available controls seem to apply here:

- Text, Edit, UpDown, Picture
- Button, Checkbox, Radio
- DropDownList, ComboBox
- ListBox, ListView, TreeView
- Link, Hotkey, DateTime
- MonthCal, Slider, Progress
- GroupBox, Tab3, StatusBar
- ActiveX (e.g. Internet Explorer Control)
- Custom

I considered using the **Picture** control and load a small picture from disk, but there are simply too many colours to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

## Code:

```
Gui Main:New,+AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption +HwndMainHwnd, PropPanelX3
Gui Main:Font,s14,Consolas
Gui Main:Add,Edit        ,vvNum1 Center x04 y04 Disabled,35.0
Gui Main:Add,DropDownList,vvColr Center x+4 y04,Pink||Yellow|Black|Blue|Red|White|Green
Gui Main:Add,Edit        ,vvNum2 Center x+4 y04 Disabled,94.0
Gui Main:Show, x300 y300 w500 h38                 ;  Show the gui
```

---

## Expected Outcome:

What I want to do is wrap this GUI window into a Function and then pass the function two RGB Hex codes, then simply render these two HEX colour codes on the GUI window:

```
MyGui("FF0000", "00FF00", <Some More Parameters>)
```

The result I am looking for is something like this image:
[image]